# MS Access updating linked table producing invalid argument error

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

I am trying to update a linked table in SQL Server through MS Access and I am getting an `Invalid argument` error. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

**UPDATE 1**

This is the call I am making and it is failing:

`sql = "UPDATE user INNER JOIN myusers ON user.userid = myuser.UserId SET myuser.division= user.division;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sql, , adExecuteNoRecords`

**UPDATE 2**

I converted the linked table to be local and applied the same update and the update was successful. I think this is due to the ODBC connection, may be someone can enlighten me on this.

Comment: show the call you are making. And possibly also the table structure. Then someone can actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that it was a PK issue. The linked table had a PK that was causing problems.