# Invalid argument Error when attempting UPDATE query on linked SharePoint list

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I'm running an UPDATE query from Access 2010 on a linked SharePoint 2013 list, but am getting an `Invalid Argument` error.

My Access DB is about 200 MB, I have tried compacting and repairing the DB. The query "runs" successfully when I select "View"--the error only appears when I actually click "Run". The query I'm running goes like:

```
UPDATE
SP_Table INNER JOIN Access_Table on SP_Table.ID1 = Access_Table.ID1
SET 
SP_Table.Field1 = Access_Table.Field1,
SP_Table.Field2 = Access_Table.Field2,
--etc...
WHERE 
(SP_Table.Field1 <> Access_Table.Field1 AND SP_Table.ID1 = Access_Table.ID1)
OR
(SP_Table.Field2 <> Access_Table.Field2 AND SP_Table.ID1 = Access_Table.ID1)
OR
--etc...
;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214694/ms-access-updating-linked-table-producing-invalid-argument-error) seems to have the same problem, and the solution even seems plausible, but they're both distinctly lacking in detail. I'm not even sure how to view the PK on my SharePoint list, or how to tell if it's the problem.

Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but I do see you are missing a comma after your first set command (`SP_Table.Field1 = Access_Table.Field1,` <- missing).  Otherwise, I don't immediately see the issue, and 200 MB shouldn't be a big deal.  Access doesn't get dicey until around 2 GB.  My only other thought is do you have a field or table name that resembles a keyword that needs to be [enclosed]?

Comment: The missing comma is a typo--also, the query "runs" successfully when I click "view", it's only when I actually hit run that the error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error, though I'm still not sure what was causing it.
I went through all of the fields in my `WHERE` clause, and narrowed the issue down to two fields that would cause the query to generate the error if they were included. I compared the fields in both tables, making sure that all of the field settings were identical, but wasn't able to make the query work with them.

Fortunately for me, these fields were not particularly vital, and I can leave them out, but if anyone else has any thoughts, I'd love to have a deeper understanding about what's causing the issue.

**EDIT**

The error cropped up again in a field that I did care about, so I had to figure out what was causing it. It looks like the "Invalid Argument" error can be caused by a few things, including having the size of either the SharePoint list, SharePoint site, or Access DB being too large. In my case, it appears that I was a victim of corrupt data.

After narrowing down which field was causing the issue, I went through and updated most of the data elements manually on the SharePoint list. Doing that apparently overwrote the corrupt data element that was causing my error, because when I ran the query again, the last few records updated without any issue.

**Bottom line**, if this happens again, I'm going to check the size of the SP list (no more than 5,000 rows), the size of the SP site (ymmv), the size of the Access DB (no more than 2GB) and then narrow down which field is giving me the error, and try replacing those data elements one at a time until I find the corrupted data element.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Sharepoint Library -- Version Settings -- Require documents to be checked out set to Yes caused this issue. I set this radio button to No and now I can update SharePoint Library fields from MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Turns out I was returning all rows from one table and only those that matched in the other. There was a missing row in the second table. Change the query to return only rows that match both tables and the problem was sorted.